# Failed to release mocks - Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am trying to upgrade from Mockito version 1.0.19 to 4.0.0 and using Junit 5, since I am unable to mock static in older version of mockito. I am getting "Failed to Release mocks" error..

Please let me know , what all needs to be taken care while migrating.

```
public class RefreshTableSchedulerTest {

    @Mock
    ConfigRepository configRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    RandomScheduler randomScheduler;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        setReflectionUtils(randomScheduler);

    }

@Test
    public void testRefreshTableWithOutDelay() {
    // our trestcases

    }
```

RandomScheduler

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class RandomScheduler {

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${schedule.refresh.table.job.in.ms:1800000}")
    public void execute() {
    //fetch data from table A
    //inserts data to Table B using timestamps got from Table A
    //updates timestamp of Table A
    }
```

Comment: Please share your stack trace

Comment: Posting your test dependencies would also help.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` on top of the test class and removing `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` from `setUp` method.

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to Release mocks` can happen when your dependencies are not aligned. Since you are using Spring Boot, make sure to not bump major Mockito version, but rather use `spring-boot-starter-test` and correct version of Spring Boot parent that will bring aligned set of dependencies including Mockito.

Comment: That's a tiny bit ambiguous, can you add an example of dependency versions for each (that work together) so we can 'see' the example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to mock static class using mockito, you will need the following dependency first. If you try to mock static class without this dependency it will throw that error

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then mock the static class by using

```
MockedStatic<YourStaticClass> yourStaticClass = mockStatic(YourStaticClass.class)
```

Also make sure whether you are using the correct dependencies in your pom

Answer (score 0):

In my case I faced this similar error on Android. The reason was the following issue: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2302

I work around it as suggested in the issue: debuggable release.