# Unit test failing after adding a new unit test for an Aspect

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, aop

I am facing a weird issue and I'm not able to find out the root cause.

I added a new unit test for an aspect that I have created and that is causing most of the test cases in the application to fail due to Mockito errors. Once I remove the test case, everything passes magically.

Annotation

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface ValidCheck {
        boolean enabled() default true;
    }
```

Aspect

```
    @Aspect
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class ValidCheckService {
        
        @Value("${field.to.validate}")
        private String field;
    
        @Around(value = "@annotation(com.test.logging.annotations.ValidCheck)")
        public ResponseEntity<?> validateFields(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    
            try {
                Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
                var validCheck =
                        ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(ValidCheck.class);
    
                if (validCheck.enabled()) {
    
                    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
                        var someClass =
                                Arrays.stream(args)
                                        .filter(arg -> arg instanceof SomeClass)
                                        .findAny()
                                        .map(arg -> (SomeClass) arg)
                                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No SomeClass present"));
    
                        var fieldToCheck = someClass.getField();
    
                        if (!field.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldToCheck)) {
                            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    log.info("Check disabled");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in validating fields", e);
            }
            
            return (ResponseEntity<?>) pjp.proceed();
        }
    }
```

Test class

```
    class ValidCheckServiceTest {
        
                private ProceedingJoinPoint pjp;
            private SomeClass some;
            private ValidCheck validCheck;
            private ValidCheckService validCheckService;
        
            @BeforeEach
            public void init() {
                pjp = mock(ProceedingJoinPoint.class);
                some = mock(SomeClass.class);
                validCheck = mock(ValidCheck.class);
                MethodSignature methodSignature = mock(MethodSignature.class);
                Method method = mock(Method.class);
        
                validCheckService = new ValidCheckService();
        
                setField(validCheckService, "field", SOME_FIELD);
        
                when(pjp.getSignature()).thenReturn(methodSignature);
                when(methodSignature.getMethod()).thenReturn(method);
                when(method.getAnnotation(ValidCheck.class)).thenReturn(validCheck);
            }
        
            @Test
            void test1() throws Throwable {
        
                when(pjp.getArgs()).thenReturn(new Object[]{some, new Object()});
                when(((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(ValidCheck.class)).thenReturn(validCheck);
                when(validCheck.enabled()).thenReturn(true);
                when(some.getClientId()).thenReturn("value");
        
                var responseEntity = validCheckService.validateFields(pjp);
        
                assertEquals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
            }
        
            @Test
            void test2() throws Throwable {
        
                when(pjp.getArgs()).thenReturn(new Object[]{some, new Object()});
                when(((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(ValidCheck.class)).thenReturn(validCheck);
                when(validCheck.enabled()).thenReturn(true);
                when(some.getClientId()).thenReturn(SOME_FIELD);
                when(pjp.proceed()).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().build());
        
                var responseEntity = validCheckService.validateFields(pjp);
        
                assertNotEquals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
            }
        
            @Test
            void test3() throws Throwable {
        
                when(pjp.getArgs()).thenReturn(new Object[]{some, new Object()});
                when(((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(ValidCheck.class)).thenReturn(validCheck);
                when(validCheck.enabled()).thenReturn(false);
                when(pjp.proceed()).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().build());
        
                var responseEntity = validCheckService.validateFields(pjp);
        
                assertNotEquals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
            }
        
            @ParameterizedTest
            @ValueSource(booleans = {true, false})
            void test4(boolean enabled) throws Throwable {
        
                when(pjp.getArgs()).thenReturn(new Object[]{new Object()});
                when(((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(ValidCheck.class)).thenReturn(validCheck);
                when(validCheck.enabled()).thenReturn(enabled);
                when(pjp.proceed()).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().build());
        
                var responseEntity = validCheckService.validateFields(pjp);
        
                assertNotEquals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
            }
        
        
            private static final String SOME_FIELD = "field";
        }
```

This test runs fine from IDE. But whenever I try to run all tests at one, most of them either fails or errors out due to mockito like unfinished stubbings, NPE or failed to release mocks.

If I delete this particular test case, all the test case magically passes.

I tried matching my spring-boot-starter-test's mockito version to mockito-inline version that we are adding in our dependency separately but with no luck.

Current library versions;

```
    +- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:4.5.1:test
    +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.5.1:test
    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.5.13:test
```

Please help me in identifying the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your question and the provided code, which is a good start. In order to reproduce your problem, however, we also need the classes under test and a second test which is failing. Otherwise, every community member trying to help you will have to invent the missing classes by themselves, possibly guessing wrong about what they might look like. A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would make it much easier to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Having said that, I think that aligning the mockito artifact versions and not using a mix of core 3.5.13 and inline 4.5.1 would be a good idea. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72303688/1082681), you ought to use `spring-boot-starter-test` and the correct version of Spring Boot parent to avoid problems like yours. Without the minimal reproducer, I cannot say more at this point. And please, don't debate by commenting, simply provide the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).